# SQL to MySQL in DataGridView

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have created a program and linked that to MySQL, and I am trying to create a class, where when a user clicks the Data Row in the Data Grid View, they get all of that information input filled out where they would, originally, input the information.

```
  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

            Try
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    con.Close()
                End If
                con.Open()

                i = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value.ToString()

                cmd = con.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from studentinfo where studprogram=" & i & ""
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(dt)
                Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
                dr = cmd.BeginExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                While dr.Read
                    TBStudsiteName.Text = dr.GetString(1).ToString()
                    TBStudTFName.Text = dr.GetString(2).ToString()
                    TBStudTLName.Text = dr.GetString(3).ToString()
                    TBclassID.Text = dr.GetString(4).ToString()
                    TBStudID.Text = dr.GetString(5).ToString()
                    TBStudgender.Text = dr.GetString(6).ToString()
                    TBStudGage.Text = dr.GetString(7).ToString()
                    TBStudLang.Text = dr.GetString(8).ToString()
                    TBStudethnicity.Text = dr.GetString(9).ToString()
                    TBStudrace.Text = dr.GetString(10).ToString()
                    TBStudfundSource.Text = dr.GetString(11).ToString()
                    TBStudiep.Text = dr.GetString(12).ToString()
                    TBStudell.Text = dr.GetString(13).ToString()
                    TBStudage.Text = dr.GetString(14).ToString()
                    TBStudaddDate.Text = dr.GetString(15).ToString()
                    TBStudfName.Text = dr.GetString(16).ToString()
                    TBStudmName.Text = dr.GetString(17).ToString()
                    TBStudlName.Text = dr.GetString(18).ToString()

                End While
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try


        End Sub
```

Comment: your code seems to make everything you want without creating a class.why do you want to have one?

Comment: So, this is for a non-profit, and in order for them to update a person's information, I figured it would be easier if they click on a row of people in the Data Grid Viewer, and that information will be autofilled into the place where they input information. There, they can change whatever they want, and click "Update" and that updates the information.

Comment: Yeah sounds good., but still you have everything you need, you save i to use it for an update as WHERE clause, but please use **prepared statememts** like [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) for security reasons.